# multiplication of two values data inside table html jsreport

Tags: javascript, html, jsrender, jsreport

I need multiplication of two values data inside table html jsreport

qty * valor --> calculate inside table row by row
Everything it's ok, just need calculation

```html
<div class="items">
  <!-- DIV DA TABELA DE ITEMS -->
  <div></div>
  <table class="table-items">
    <thead>
      <tr class="tr-items">
        {{props items}} {{if key
        <=0 }} {{props prop}} <th class="th-items">{{>key}}</th>
          {{/props}} {{/if}} {{/props}}
          <th class="th-items">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{for items}}
      <tr class="tr-items">
        <td class="td-items">
          {{>date}}
        </td>
        <td class="td-items">
          {{>qty}}
        </td>
        <td class="td-items">
          {{>item}}
        </td>
        <td class="td-items">
          {{>valor}}
        </td>
        <!-- <td> {{total items}}{{/total}}</td> -->
        <td class="td-items">
          {{>qty}} * {{>valor}} €
        </td>
      </tr>
      {{/for}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried {{>qty * >valor}} ? Otherwise you might need to have the product as part of your data source.

Comment: Yes I tried this but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To performa a calculation in jsrender, surround the calculation with parentheses:

```html
<td class="td-items">
  {{>(qty * valor)}} €
</td>
```

***Breaking News***

It turns out that the "valor" property is a string of the form "50.00 EUR", so the number portion of the string needs to be extracted. This revised form will do the trick:

```
{{>(qty * valor.split(' ')[0])}}
```

It also turns out that the parentheses are optional, so this also works:

```
{{> qty * valor.split(' ')[0]}}
```

Comment: My "valor" = "50.00 EUR"

Comment: @RuiOliveira Then you'll need to convert `valor` to a number. Obviously, you can't multiply a number by a string.

Comment: Yes I know, but how convert [valor] inside table row by row?

Comment: Actually you don't need the parens. {{>qty*valor}} or  {{> qty * valor }} are  fine too (assuming qty and valor are numbers)

Comment: I put the [valor] as a string but took the[ EUR, ], inside table put this code

Comment: It's possible save "{{>(qty * +unit_price).toFixed(2)}}" inside the data {{total}}, because I need search {{total}} value for another table

Answer (score 0):

I put the [valor] as a string but took the[ EUR, ], inside table put this code :

```html
<td class="td-items">
   {{>(+valor).toFixed(2)}} EUR
</td>
<td class="td-items">
    {{>(qty * +valor).toFixed(2)}} EUR
</td>

--------------------
MY data:

    "items": [
      { 
        "date": "04/05/2020",
        "qty": 4,
        "item": "Website design",
        "valor": "50.00"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible save "{{>(qty * +unit_price).toFixed(2)}}" inside the data {{total}}, because I need search {{total}} value for another table